# How to hide report menu in odoo?

Tags: menu, report, hide, odoo, invisible

How to hide report menu? 
My code is:

```
 <report string=" Account Invoice"
            id="account_invoice"
            model="account.invoice"
            report_type="xlsx"
            invisible="[('account_invoice.type', '=', '**in_invoice**')]"
            name="account_invoice_report.xlsx"
            file="account_invoice_report.xlsx"
            attachment_use="False"/>
```

My question is if invoice type is in_invoice, hide this menu.
How to solve? I'm try invisible and domain. But not working. 
Help, I need any solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide / view your report based on condition ..
1 - hide from "Print" menu by adding in report definition :

```
menu="False"
```

2 - create a button type="object" and in his function add this code .. don't forget to add your external id of report :

```
    def print_export_sale_order(self):
        return self.env.ref('sales_enhancement.report_export_sale_order').report_action(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `invisible` attribute, instead of `'='`, I think you should use `'in'` instead,

Answer (score 0):

You can add **`Groups`** into your menu to hide from other users or else you just make it **`inactive`** for hiding it or else you can remove action from that.